# Why error: expected expression before '{' token happen when i try to initialize a struct variable

Tags: c

Here is the code I used when i try to initialize the struct L:

```
typedef struct {
    int data[20];
    int length;
} SqList;

SqList L;
L = {
 {1,2,3,4,5},
  5
 };
```

Comment: The MAXSIZE is 20, and the ElemType is declare as typedef int ElemType

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed, wanting to initialize first and re-assign later is a much common need, and compiler screams this error.  This is not addressed here, nor in the duplicate :-(

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing but assigning, because declaration of `L` and assigning a value are two separate statements in your code.

Write

```
SqList L = {
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    5
};
```

and it should work.

You can overwrite this initial value later, but note that you need to assign an SqList-object then, and the assignment must happen in the context of a function:

```
int main() {
    L = (SqList){ {1,2,3,4,5}, 5 };
}
```

Comment: You can initiate like this also `SqList L = {
        .data = {1,2,3,4},
        .length = 4
    };`

Comment: Thanks, it did work @Stephan Lechner

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, please do not forget to accept the answer